# how to map skydrive as network drive in windows xp?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, onedrive

how can I map my skydrive as a network drive in Windows XP/2003?

again i need it in windows xp/2003 not 7 neither Vista

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows XP you can map a skydrive by following these steps.

1) Get your skydrive 16 digit skydrive "cid".

Using your web browser login to your skydrive account. When you're logged in, right click the skydrive logo in the top left and select "copy link address". You'll get a URL that looks like this:

https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=0123456789ABCDEF (where 0123456789ABCDEF is your cid)

copy the cid somewhere. You'll need it in a minute.

2) Add a Network Place in Windows XP.

Open File Explorer and select Tools / Map Network Drive. In the bottom of the Network Drive dialogue click "Sign up for online storage or connect to a network server". This will bring you to the Add Network Place Wizard. Click Next. Select "Choose another network location". In the Internet or network address box put in the following URL:

https://d.docs.live.net/0123456789ABCDEF (where 0123456789ABCDEF is your cid)

Click Next. Type a name. I made mine "Document @ Skydrive".

You might / should be prompted with a login at some point.

Good luck!

Comment: how about accepting this answer @user1512094? ;) it'll be my first.

Comment: doesnt work for me. Login succeeds but then explorer fails to load files. All looked promising until the final hurdle :( (I'm using XP)

Comment: Strange. I thought maybe Microsoft had changed something but my mapping is still working. You should see the link that you created under the "My Network Places" of File Explorer. What happens when it "fails"? A timeout? An error message?

Comment: Helpful, but the mapping shows up under "My Network Places" and doesn't quite behave as nicely as other cloud drives like Google Drive.  I can't save to this kind of XP Skydrive directly from applications; I have to save it somewhere else first and then copy it there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to *map* a skydrive (or TeamCenter location, as it is in my case).

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit old question, but yes, this can be done very easily.

[Here](http://www.expandrive.com/) is an app that does that. It works not only for OveDrive but also for Dropbox, Google Drive, S3, SFTP WebDAV and many other cloud storage solutions.